# How can I show that ~ is an equivalence relation such that $x$~$y$ if there is a continuous path in $M$ from $x$ to $y$?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a metric space $M$, we will define a relation ~ on $M$ by defining $x$~$y$ if there is a continuous path in $M$ from $x$ to $y$.

I'd like to show that ~ is an equivalence relation.

I am stuck how to do this, do I make up some function?

Comment: What is the definition of an equivalence relation? What properties should it satisfy? How can we show that this relation satisfies these properties?

Comment: @in_wolfram_we_trust:  your faith is misplaced! ;-)

Comment: @1950RobertLewis Who would you have me follow? :P

Comment: @in_wolfram_we_trust:  Follow your heart, man . . . other than that, I got nothin' for you on this . . . anyway, I'm not the best exemplar/authority on such matters, so maybe wolfram is OK; have *met* the guy?  I have! ;-) :P

Comment: @in_wolfram_we_trust:  we all know wolfram's $A(\alpha)$, what about wolfram's $\Omega$?

Comment: @1950RobertLewis I understand he's not a great guy, but he makes great tools. My username should really be "in_wolfram_alpha_we_trust"

Comment: @in_wolfram_we_trust:  that sound's a lot safer!  I think the *tool* is awesome.  Wolfram himself is a certifiable genius, with the accompanying idosyncracies.  That's all I'll say here!  Actually, Wolfram *is* awesome, in his own way, as is his *tool*! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints**

- A *path* from $a$ to $b$ is a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to M$ such that $f(0) = x$, $f(1) = y$.
- For symmetry, consider $g(t) = f(1-t)$.
- For transitivity, if $f_1$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ and $f_2$ from $y$ to $z$, consider $$
  g(t) =
  \begin{cases}
  f_1(2t) & 0 \le t \le \frac12 \\
  f_2(2t - 1) & \frac12 \le t \le 1 \\
  \end{cases}
  $$

Comment: If you require a path to be injective, how do you show the relation is reflexive?

Comment: If you require a path to be injective, this relation will *not* be an equivalence relation on spaces $X$ which do not admit an injective map $S^1 \rightarrow X$. $X=\mathbb{R}$ is one such space, so requiring a path to be injective turns out to be a very strange choice.

Comment: @SantiagoCanez I got rid of the injective requirement for now.  I don't have my analysis book with me or I would go back and check how we defined paths...I had thought they were required to be injective but maybe I'm mixing up complex and real paths.

Comment: @JakobOesinghaus That is interesting.  However, I don't see how this is not an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{R}$.  Any two points have a continuous injective function between them in $\mathbb{R}$, so that means any two points are equivalent, which makes this trivially an equivalence relation.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @Goos - if we require paths to be injective, we don't have $x$ ~ $x$.

Comment: @user73985 Ah, that is a problem.  Maybe this is fixed if we allow the domain to be any closed interval $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the continuous path from $y$ to $x$ to show that $y$ is equivalent to $x$ if $x$ is eqivalent to $y$.   So we know that the path from $x$ to $y$ is given by some continuous function $f:I \rightarrow M$, where $I=[0,1]$.  Further, we know that $f(0)=x$ and $f(1)=y$.  Then think about $g(t)=f(1-t)$.  Does this function work?  Why?  Is it continuous?  Transitivity of the relation can be shown similarly.  And clearly $x$ is equivalent to itself by the constant map.  Does this help?

Comment: When you say: "Further, we know that $f(0) = x$ and $f(1)=y$", do you mean "we define $f(0) = x$ and $f(1)=y$?"

Comment: We know that if $f$ is the path, then it has those properties by the definition of a path, so we can assume them to be true in this case.

Comment: To show the equivalence relation, we assume such a path exists from $x$ to $y$